# How to use the Library functions in its Unit

Tags: delphi, dll

I have a Library "Utilities.DPR" which contains its Child Unit called "Container.Pas". There are some functions which are in the Library "Utilities.DPR". I'm able to use the functions defined and declared in Container.pas which and call into its Library.dpr unit. But there are some functions in the Library unit also which I want to use.

```
library Utilities;

{ Important note about DLL memory management: ShareMem must be the
  first unit in your library's USES clause AND your project's (select
  Project-View Source) USES clause if your DLL exports any procedures or
  functions that pass strings as parameters or function results. This
  applies to all strings passed to and from your DLL--even those that
  are nested in records and classes. ShareMem is the interface unit to
  the BORLNDMM.DLL shared memory manager, which must be deployed along
  with your DLL. To avoid using BORLNDMM.DLL, pass string information
  using PChar or ShortString parameters. }

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, windows, Winapi.Messages, System.Variants, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,System.NetEncoding, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  DCPcrypt2, DCPblockciphers, DCPblowfish, DCPsha256, IdGlobal,
  Types, Soap.EncdDecd, IdCoder,IdCoderMIME, LbCipher, Winsock,
  DateUtils,
  container in 'container.pas' {frmContainer};

{$R *.res}
var
    s,n,Temp:widestring;
    length_:integer;

function bitshifter(Const TestStr:WideString):Boolean;
begin
      ....
      ....

end;
```

and

```
unit container;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, FireDAC.Stan.Def,
  LbClass,DateUtils;

type
  TfrmContainer = class(TForm)
    FDSQLiteFunc: TFDSQLiteFunction;
    SQLiteConn: TSQLConnection;
    FDSQLiteRTree: TFDSQLiteRTree;
    FDSQLiteBkp: TFDSQLiteBackup;
    SQLQuery: TSQLQuery;
    FDSQLiteValidate1: TFDSQLiteValidate;
    FDLocalSQL1: TFDLocalSQL;
    FDConn: TFDConnection;
    FDQuery1: TFDQuery;
    FDSQLiteSec: TFDSQLiteSecurity;
    FDGUIxWaitCursor1: TFDGUIxWaitCursor;
    FDPhysSQLiteDriverLink1: TFDPhysSQLiteDriverLink;

    procedure FDSQLiteValidate1Progress(ASender: TFDPhysDriverService;
      const AMessage: string);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

function CheckSQLiteDLL:boolean;
function CheckAllowed(const s: string): boolean;

var
  frmContainer: TfrmContainer;



implementation

procedure TfrmContainer.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
      //Connection should be created once only)
      bitshifter('Hello');
      ....
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be more specific about your problem. eg. if you need to access `bitshifter` you have to `export` it and then import by declaring as `external`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Delphi the **dpr** file is essentially just a special type of unit.  One difference between the **dpr** and other units is that you cannot **use** it from other units.

Another thing to be aware of is that two units cannot use each other in their interface sections.  This would create a *circular unit reference*, which is not permitted.

So, taking your case as an example:

Utilities DPR:

- Implements **bitshifter** function
- Uses **Containers** unit

Containers PAS:

- A form which needs to use **bitshifter** function

For the **bitshifter** function to be made available to other units it must first be moved to a unit itself **or** moved to the unit where it is used.

i.e. you could just move it to the **Containers** unit.  But it is not really a good idea to move a general purpose utility function, which this appears to be, to a unit which implements a very specific component of a UI (since in this case **Containers** is a form unit).

It would make more sense here to create a new unit specifically for this and any related routines.  In this case we might create a unit called **BitUtilities.pas**.

If the DPR contains code that uses the function then the DPR needs to use both the existing **Containers** unit as well as the new **BitUtilities** unit.  You may wish to have the DPR use this unit even if it *doesn't* call the functions within it directly since having the DPR aware of all units used in a project can help ensure that certain IDE facilities work as expected (e.g. ctrl+click navigation of referenced functions etc).

Otherwise, the **Containers** unit simply needs to use **BitUtilities**:

Utilities DPR:

- Uses **BitUtilities** unit (optional, *unless* the DPR also contains code which calls the **bitshifter** function itself)
- Uses **Containers** unit

BitUtilities PAS:

- Implements the **bitshifter** function (and any other similar/related "bit" functions)

Containers PAS:

- Uses the **BitUtilities** unit

Answer (score 0):

Units cannot reference symbols declared in the project file. For *container* to call `bitshifter`, you need to move the function into a unit. It could be *container*, or it could be some other unit.